# created_at and updated_at not working automatically in laravel 5.6 when use model::insert() . why?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

```
ProductCategory::insert($insertData);
```

I am using this above statement passing an array for inserting multiple record `$insertData` working fine but when check my `created_at` and `updated_at` column not getting timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `create()` (remember to set [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)):

```
foreach($insertData as $data) {
    ProductCategory::create($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `insert()` method is a direct SQL statement by the `QueryBuilder`. It converts your array of values into a query statement to insert without mutators or other magic.

You can do a couple things to set these values. You can loop through an do a single insert for each row of data using `ProductCategory::create($array);`. Which will do a query per insert.

Or you can add the `created_at` and `updated_at` values to your array collection directly. Laravel has a method built in to set the updated at column on an array  `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::addUpdatedAtColumn()` if you wanted to loop through `$insertData` and set it. If you look at it you'll see it just applies to the `updated_at` column. You need the `created_at` value too.

I would recommend you doing something like this if you wish to keep a single insert statement:

```
$object = new ProductCategory();
$insertData = array_map(function ($data) use ($object) {
    $timestamp = $object->freshTimestampString();
    $data[$object->getUpdatedAtColumn()] = $timestamp;
    $data[$object->getCreatedAtColumn()] = $timestamp;
    return $data;
}, $insertData);
$object->insert($insertData);
```

Comment: thanks you all for the suggestion. but i have one more question. How to Update Multiple record in laravel 5.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Laravel Eloquent` feature to make timestamps written to the Database automatically, when you insert data directly, `Laravel` does not know about your timestamps. You need to set the timestamps manually in the insert statement.

**Use Eloquent models**, like following :-

```
foreach($insertData as $data) {
 ProductCategory::create($data);
}
```

[Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)